how to solve the issue of renderObject.markNeedsBuild(); not present in flutter
I am using Syncfusion in my flutter code, and after generating an APK, I was unable to see the images and text. While trying to correct that image issue, I got this error and now do not know what to do:
/C:/Users/Gabby/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.9/lib/src/charts/cartesian_chart.dart:1367:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder<Constraints, RenderObject>'.
 - 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gabby/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
 - 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gabby/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gabby/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
        renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception

How can I solve this error?
I tried cleaning the cache and running the command to get an APK, but that didn't fix my issue.

check that answer

workaround was to edit packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart, find mixin RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder and add there this code:
  void markNeedsBuild() {
    markNeedsLayout();

}

check comment

For the record I worked around it by degrading the version of the SyncFusion libraries to earlier version 22.2.9. I prefer not to mess with the third party code since I do not need the new features of the charts, grids.

Edit packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart,
mixin RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder<ConstraintType extends Constraints, ChildType extends RenderObject> on RenderObjectWithChildMixin<ChildType> {
  //ADD THIS METHOD...
  void markNeedsBuild() { 
    markNeedsLayout();
  }
  
  LayoutCallback<ConstraintType>? _callback;
  /// Change the layout callback.
  void updateCallback(LayoutCallback<ConstraintType>? value) {
    if (value == _callback) {
      return;
    }
    _callback = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }


workaround was to edit packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart, find mixin RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder and add there this code:
void markNeedsBuild() {
markNeedsLayout();
}

The team upgraded their Flutter Charts package to be compatible with Flutter SDK 3.24.0. By upgrading Flutter Charts to the latest version we can resolve the issue.
Charts: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/versions/26.2.14

Issue is solve with syncfusion_flutter_charts version 26.2.14 builds and runs with Flutter stable release 3.24.0.
Referance Link: https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/issues/2008
